# how to setup cakephp that runs from url path

Tags: docker, nginx, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

So I'm building microservice architecture and I have separate cakePHP installations for Administration and Partners. So https://example.com is going to be served for normal users and that works fine as it's a standard installation.

But I can't figure out how to set up other two that they work as https://example.com/admin and https://example.com/partners. I use nginx to direct traffic to the correct docker container running admin and partners cakephp. Problem is how to let CakePHP know that his root website path is `/admin` and not just `\`? Because all the routing gets messed up.

I'm using CakePHP 4.x and PHP 7.2.x

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply change the `App.baseUrl` in the cakephp configuration. For more info check the [official documentation](http://%20https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/configuration.html)

Comment: actually I just had to modify routes.php with `$routes->scope('/admin' ...` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good option to create multiple projects for different AUTH (Partner/Administration). Cakephp allow multiple authentication for different roles.
Example: for a school project I had created Admin/School/Teacher/Students using different AUTH and AUTH storage , which never conflict with each other.

In your case there is a solution .
Assuming that you want to  use https://example.com/ and Partner and https://example.com/admin as administrator.

1.First host your Partner project in ROOT.

2. Create a folder , named  "admin" in Partner root projects folder.
3. Copy/Move your admin project code to your "admin" folder.
4. Change/update your ".htaccess" files in Partner root folder(FOR APACHE).

APACHE CODE

```
# Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    admin    admin/    [L]
    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

After "RewriteEngine on " a new line added to bypass the PARTNER cakephp.

NGINX

```
# nginx configuration by winginx.com

location / {
  rewrite admin /admin/ break;
  rewrite ^/(\.well-known/.*)$ /$1 break;
  rewrite ^/$ /webroot/ break;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 break;
}
```

Comment: it's a microservice structure that is why this is structured the way it is. I do not have different projects just for different auth group. All microservices use same user table for login, they just look at what rights user has

Comment: @David-lednik, you have mentioned than you have `I have separate cakePHP installations`